# Ensure that ICommand implementation properly uses weak references

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, reference, weak-references

I am building an implementation of `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` that is like the commonly used `RelayCommand`, but doesn't keep a strong reference to targets of the delegates it uses. Such a structure is useful for when a control wants to expose some of its functionality as a command (which can be assigned to a ViewModel). Using a traditional `RelayCommand` would cause a memory leak, because the `RelayCommand` would contain strong references to the delegates that it runs, which in turn contain strong references to the control. Here is the code:

```
public class WeakRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public WeakRelayCommand(Action<object> executeCallback, Func<object, bool> canExecuteCallback = null)
    {
        ExecuteTargetReference = new WeakReference<object>(executeCallback.Target);
        if (canExecuteCallback != null)
            CanExecuteTargetReference = new WeakReference<object>(canExecuteCallback.Target);
        ExecuteCallbackInfo = executeCallback.GetMethodInfo();
        CanExecuteCallbackInfo = canExecuteCallback?.GetMethodInfo();
    }

    private WeakReference<object> ExecuteTargetReference;
    private WeakReference<object> CanExecuteTargetReference;
    private MethodInfo ExecuteCallbackInfo;
    private MethodInfo CanExecuteCallbackInfo;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecuteCallbackInfo == null)
            return true;
        object canExecuteTarget = null;
        if (CanExecuteTargetReference?.TryGetTarget(out canExecuteTarget) ?? false)
        {
            return (bool)CanExecuteCallbackInfo.Invoke(canExecuteTarget, new[] { parameter });
        }
        else
            return false; //Target of the delegate for CanExecute has been garbage collected
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        object executeTarget = null;
        if (ExecuteTargetReference?.TryGetTarget(out executeTarget) ?? false)
        {
            ExecuteCallbackInfo.Invoke(executeTarget, new[] { parameter });
        }
        //Cannot execute the command if the target of the Execute delegate has been garbage collected
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The basic summary is that instead of holding strong references to delegates, which in turn hold strong references to the delegates' targets of invocation, it instead holds a reference to the `MethodInfo` associated with the actual method of the delegate, and holds a `WeakReference` to the targets of invocation separately from the method. This way, the targets of invocation are free to be garbage collected by the garbage collector.

I have tested this implementation and it works just fine as an implementation of ICommand, and it appears to properly use WeakReferences to achieve my objective. Can I get a verification that this is in fact the case?

Comment: Actually, I can not see the use case for that class. If the passed delegate is garbage collected, the command becomes useless, isn't it?

Comment: The use case is for an MVVM application where the ViewModel needs to send a signal to the view, but not through a bound property. The most elegant way I've found is to use ICommands, but in the reverse order, e.g., in addition to the model calling the VM's commands, the VM calls the model's commands. This causes a backwards object lifecycle (creating a memory leak), as well as circular references, however, so this is why I need a "weak relay command."

Comment: Yes, once the target is garbage collected, the command does indeed become useless (and CanExecute() forever returns false). However, under my use case, it is the view that is GC'd first (after user interaction is gone for sure), then the VM, so the VM would not normally need to use the command after the view is GC'd. Something just had to be done about the circular strong reference loop, otherwise nothing would be GC'd, which is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation works fine if the passed delegate is an instance method, because that prevents the method from being garbage collected.

But that is not necessarily the case. Lambda expression, for instance, will be garbage collected sometime because they are not referenced somewhere else. 
That may result in strange not reproducible bugs that are hard to debug.

The following code (with a simplified version of the `WeakRelayCommand` class) shows that the weak reference approach does not work for static methods and lambda expressions with closures.

```
void Main()
{
    var longLiveObject = new DummyObject();
    var commands = GetActions(longLiveObject);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    foreach (var command in commands)
        Console.WriteLine(command.Name + "\t IsAlive:" + command.IsAlive);
}

private static WeakAction[] GetActions(DummyObject longLiveObject)
{
    var localObj = new DummyObject();
    return new []
    {
        new WeakAction("InstanceMethod (short living)", localObj.InstanceMethod),
        new WeakAction("InstanceMethod (long living)", longLiveObject.InstanceMethod),
        new WeakAction("StaticMethod", DummyObject.StaticMethod),
        new WeakAction("LamdaExpression (without closure)", o => { }),
        new WeakAction("LamdaExpression (with closure)", o => localObj.InstanceMethod(o)),
    };
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class DummyObject
{
    public void InstanceMethod(object obj) { }
    public static void StaticMethod(object obj) {}  
}

public class WeakAction
{
    private readonly WeakReference<object> _targetReference;
    private readonly MethodInfo _callbackInfo;

    public WeakAction(string name, Action<object> executeCallback)
    {
        Name = name;
        _targetReference = new WeakReference<object>(executeCallback.Target);
        _callbackInfo = executeCallback.GetMethodInfo();        
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public bool IsAlive
    {
        get
        {
            object obj;
            return _targetReference.TryGetTarget(out obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
InstanceMethod (short living)        IsAlive:False
InstanceMethod (long living)         IsAlive:True 
StaticMethod                        IsAlive:False 
LamdaExpression (without closure)   IsAlive:True 
LamdaExpression (with closure)      IsAlive:False
```

Comment: Good points. I should update this to add support for static methods (as strange as it sounds), because it is possible for one of (Execute, CanExecute) to be a static method and the other an instance method, which would not be supported by my implementation.

Comment: Interesting point about the Lambda expressions, but I have a question. Doesn't using reflection to get the MethodInfo of the lambda expression create a hard copy of the contents of the expression without the target? Or is MethodInfo itself essentially a weak reference to the lambda expression? Because the whole implementation depends on the delegate (lambda or not) being garbage collected while retaining a copy of the method (without the target) in the form of a MethodInfo.

Comment: You are right... the problem does not appear with lambda expressions in general... It seems only a problem if the lambda expressions contain closures (see updated answer).

Comment: Well even that's actually not a problem, because in that case, the intended behavior is that the target of invocation is GC'd, and the command is useless. Normally when the command is being used, something will be holding a strong reference to the target anyway, which will prevent it from being GC'd.